# Wifi connection drops randomply and can't connect until reboot

Tags: networking, drivers, iwlwifi

Doing: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

I get this:

```
[ 3045.514398] RIP: 0010:iwl_fwrt_dump_lmac_error_log+0x4cf/0x550 [iwlwifi]
[ 3045.514434]  iwl_fwrt_dump_error_logs+0x29/0x220 [iwlwifi]
[ 3045.514450]  iwl_mvm_nic_error+0xfe/0x120 [iwlmvm]
[ 3045.514465]  iwl_trans_sync_nmi_with_addr+0xa6/0x140 [iwlwifi]
[ 3045.514477]  iwl_trans_pcie_sync_nmi+0x68/0x80 [iwlwifi]
[ 3045.514489]  iwl_fw_dbg_error_collect+0x60/0xe0 [iwlwifi]
[ 3045.514504]  iwl_mvm_up+0x106/0x9f0 [iwlmvm]
[ 3045.514525]  __iwl_mvm_mac_start+0x6f/0xf0 [iwlmvm]
[ 3045.514535]  iwl_mvm_mac_start+0x63/0x130 [iwlmvm]
[ 3045.514748] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: HW error, resetting before reading
[ 3045.538480] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 34.0.1 8265-34.ucode
[ 3045.538483] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[ 3045.538485] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status0
[ 3045.538486] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[ 3045.538488] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | branchlink2
[ 3045.538489] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | interruptlink1
[ 3045.538490] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | interruptlink2
[ 3045.538491] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | data1
[ 3045.538493] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | data2
[ 3045.538494] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3
[ 3045.538495] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[ 3045.538497] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf low
[ 3045.538498] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[ 3045.538499] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[ 3045.538501] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp2
[ 3045.538502] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode revision type
[ 3045.538503] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode version major
[ 3045.538504] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode version minor
[ 3045.538506] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | hw version
[ 3045.538507] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | board version
[ 3045.538508] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | hcmd
[ 3045.538510] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr0
[ 3045.538511] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[ 3045.538512] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr2
[ 3045.538513] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr3
[ 3045.538515] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[ 3045.538516] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[ 3045.538517] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[ 3045.538519] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[ 3045.538520] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[ 3045.538521] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[ 3045.538523] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[ 3045.538524] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[ 3045.538525] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[ 3045.538527] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | flow_handler
[ 3045.556211] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[ 3045.556213] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[ 3045.556215] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink2
[ 3045.556216] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink1
[ 3045.556217] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[ 3045.556219] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac data1
[ 3045.556220] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac data2
[ 3045.556221] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac data3
[ 3045.556223] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac major
[ 3045.556224] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac minor
[ 3045.556225] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | frame pointer
[ 3045.556227] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | stack pointer
[ 3045.556228] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[ 3045.556229] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[ 3045.573918] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: IML/ROM dump:
[ 3045.573920] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x5A5A | IML/ROM SYSASSERT
[ 3045.573922] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x5A5A5A5A | IML/ROM error/state
[ 3045.591635] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x5A5A5A5A | IML/ROM data1
[ 3047.567206] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: mac start retry 0
[ 3048.280821] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
[ 3048.280828] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to start INIT ucode: -5
[ 3048.280831] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
[ 3048.280832] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -5
[ 3048.280841] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Collecting data: trigger 16 fired.
[ 3048.316288] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 657 at drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwl-trans.h:1414 iwl_fwrt_dump_lmac_error_log+0x4cf/0x550 [iwlwifi]
[ 3048.316314] Modules linked in: rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio bnep nvidia_uvm(POE) snd_soc_avs snd_soc_skl snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core intel_tcc_cooling x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_hwdep intel_powerclamp snd_pcm nvidia_drm(POE) coretemp snd_seq_midi nvidia_modeset(POE) snd_seq_midi_event uvcvideo iwlmvm videobuf2_vmalloc snd_rawmidi kvm_intel btusb binfmt_misc i915 nvidia(POE) videobuf2_memops kvm mac80211 btrtl drm_buddy crct10dif_pclmul mei_pxp mei_hdcp intel_rapl_msr nls_iso8859_1 libarc4 ghash_clmulni_intel videobuf2_v4l2 snd_seq btbcm ttm joydev btintel aesni_intel videobuf2_common snd_seq_device btmtk drm_display_helper crypto_simd iwlwifi cryptd snd_timer videodev cec
```

What should I do?

Comment: Don't post logvomit. Yours shows no problem, see all the "`OK`"s. Look at `service NetworkManager status`, and read `man journalctl`.

Comment: How can you tell everything is "OK"? Aren't the first three lines errors? Anyway, thanks for the advice. I need to run those 2 commands from the terminal as soon as I will encounter the problem again, right?

Comment: Please try this workaround; create a file under `/etc/modprobe.d/` with suffix `.conf`  and following content `options iwlwifi enable_ini=N` this will not preventing firmware to crash but the system won't try to dump the crash.

Comment: With more recent kernels 6.5+ you might lose your wifi connection with this error in dmesg `iwlwifi: 'N' invalid for parameter 'enable_ini'` you need to change the `N` to a `0` i.e. `options iwlwifi enable_ini=0`. See https://groups.google.com/g/linux.debian.bugs.dist/c/ivTqsbhwVD8?pli=1